# Get the value of the array index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajax response array and I want get the value of there index.

> [{"UserLatitude":"33.7543","UserLongitude":"-84.3744"}{"UserLatitude":"22.6962","UserLongitude":"75.8651"},{"UserLatitude":"22.6963","UserLongitude":"75.8654"},{"UserLatitude":"37.7858","UserLongitude":"-122.406"},{"UserLatitude":"0","UserLongitude":"0"},{"UserLatitude":"37.7858","UserLongitude":"-122.406"},{"UserLatitude":"37.7858","UserLongitude":"-122.406"},{"UserLatitude":"37.7858","UserLongitude":"-122.406"},{"UserLatitude":"0","UserLongitude":"0"},{"UserLatitude":"0","UserLongitude":"0"},{"UserLatitude":"22.6962","UserLongitude":"75.8653"},{"UserLatitude":"22.6963","UserLongitude":"75.8654"},{"UserLatitude":"0","UserLongitude":"0"},{"UserLatitude":"33.7543","UserLongitude":"-84.3745"},{"UserLatitude":"0","UserLongitude":"0"},{"UserLatitude":"0","UserLongitude":"0"},{"UserLatitude":"33.7543","UserLongitude":"-84.3744"}]

Comment: Describe what you need and show what you have tried.

Comment: i want to get the value of UserLatitude and UserLongitude, and i have try to use result[0].UserLatitude for single value but this is not working so please help me tanks

Comment: i want like this  UserLatitude=33.7543 and UserLongitude = -84.37744

Comment: is `UserLongitude = -84.37744`?  or `UserLongitude = -84.3744 `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the first array object which is causing an error. Otherwise `result[0].UserLatitude` will work - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6nGK/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array and then check those values are matching like

```
$.each (arr, function (index, value) { 
    if(value["UserLatitude"] == "33.7543" && value["UserLongitude"] == "-84.3744") {
        console.log(index);
        return false;
    }
});
```

if matches found, print the **`index`** and exit the loop.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/E6nGK/1/)